# What happened to android.provider.Telephony?

Tags: java, android, message

Does anyone know what happened to `android.provider.Telephony`? It is not there anymore.

Answer (score 5):

If you read [this](http://www.mail-archive.com/android-developers@googlegroups.com/msg11410.html) post from the android-developer mailing list you can see that `android.provider.Telephony` is part of the Open Source releases, but never included as part of the Official SDK.

Meaning you are free to view it, to gain a understanding of how the underlying system works, but you can't actually reference and compile against it in your Android application(s).

Comment: i have downloded MMS app from git..when ever i execute that project its showing errors at import android.provider.Telephney...i want to implement this code into my project ..then what to do..

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Brian, however, it seems Telephony is used by code posted on [this site](http://www.anddev.org/recognize-react_on_incoming_sms-t295.html).

In this excerpt from Apress (ISBN: 978-1-43021-064-1) by Chris Haseman, it is used too:

> Telephony class is used for sms messaging,
>
> ```
> (Context context, Intent intent)
> {
> SmsMessage msg[] =
>     Telephony.Sms.Intents.getMessagesFromIntent(intent);
> ...
> ```

Answer (score 1):

The code you linked to on anddev.org is for SDK version **m5-rc14** which is from February, 2008 almost an entire year old. The current SDK version is 1.0, with two releases between it and m5-rc14.

Given the nature of the Android project they have added and removed many interfaces in its rapid growth/adoption. A lot of people have complained that they are closing out some of the interfaces to some cool parts of the operating system, such as the Telephony interface.

You can check out android.telephony ([link](http://code.google.com/android/reference/android/telephony/package-summary.html)) package and see if there is equivalent functionality there.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use it to get data from your current reception signal.
Check [this tutorial](http://www.firstdroid.com/2010/05/12/get-provider-gsm-signal-strength/)- it uses the telephony manager to get data.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to send an SMS message with the G1 using the following library:
android.telephony.gsm.SmsManager

So at least (for the SMS send/receive code) there is an equivalent library available.

Also be sure to check out the TelephonyManager
http://code.google.com/android/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html

This isn't exactly what you were asking about, but it does provide a lot of the functionality you're looking for.

As for the APress book reference in the answer above, I wrote it.  As of right now, it's a little out of date (It was published before the 1.0 SDK was published) and I'm almost done updating it.  Ahhh the joys of rapidly updating technology.