# How to check android device's PLMN?

Tags: android

I want to get phone operator PLMN number.
I saw some solutions that uses android.provider.Telephone, but it is the internal class, so I suppose it is a not good solution to call it by reflection. 
Do you have any other ideas?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

the solutions in android.provider.Telephony will not work becauce that package not exist in real SDK, so you can't reflect it
[What happened to android.provider.Telephony?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499528/what-happened-to-android-provider-telephony)
I'm searching for a solution too