# Where to find the definition/description of Android's SMS_RECEIVED or similiar thing?

Tags: android

I don't know where I can find the definition or detailed description of SMS_RECEIVED, which could be set as below:

```
<action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
```

I searched it on website http://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html, but no result.
Thanks!

And also this one:

```
<uses -permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"></uses>
```

This kind of usage is in `AndroidManifest.xml` file. And what confuses me is that how do I know them? Where to find them? I can find them only from other guys' projects? No official douments at all?

Comment: It never was the part of the official SDK. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/499528/what-happened-to-android-provider-telephony

Comment: Now I know that, but where to find the official document of them? Only refer to others' projects to track them and learn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer I find is below: Now I find it in the source code below:

@SdkConstant(SdkConstantType.BROADCAST_INTENT_ACTION)
public static final String SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION =
        "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";

which is in file: `~/android-sdks/sources/android-16/android/provider/Telephony.java` And for the whole file `Telephony.java`, it is marked with `@hide` (as below). That should be the reason why I cannot find SMS_RECEIVED via javadoc.

```
/**
 * The Telephony provider contains data related to phone operation.
 *
 * @hide
 */
```